# Ember data post form data as JSON

Tags: json, ember.js

Common feature - register user - store data in mongodb. 
In postman everything is ok, I can't make it good from app ui although.

My controller:

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
actions: {
    addUser: function(){
        let formData = {
            "fullname": this.get('fullname'),
            "firstname": this.get('firstname'),
            "lastname": this.get('lastname'),
            "email": this.get('email')
        };

        let newUser = this.store.createRecord('candidate',{
            fullname: formData.fullname,
            firstname: formData.firstname,
            lastname: formData.lastname,
            email: formData.email
        })
        newUser.save();

    }
}
});
```

My adapter:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    namespace: 'api'
});
```

My model:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  fullname: DS.attr('string'),
  firstname: DS.attr('string'),
  lastname: DS.attr('string'),
  email: DS.attr('string')
});
```

post request is successful with 201 status. In db I see new empty document. In console I see error "SyntaxError: Unexpected token C in JSON at position 0"
I guess I should have declare JSON.parse. In adapter? Making  JSON.parse(newUser) doesn't help. 
I am newbie with ember so I guess I silly mistake but I cannot find any.

Comment: You can just print the content and verify it `console.log('formdata',formData);` and also you can pass it like this `this.store.createRecord('candidate',formData)`

Comment: in console formData is normal JSON as declared, newUser is object class with bunch of properties.

Comment: What do you see in the network tab? What does the request look like?

Comment: **REQUEST HEADER**POST <br/>/api/candidates HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8000<br/>
Connection: keep-alive<br/>
Content-Length: 92<br/>
Pragma: no-cache<br/>
Cache-Control: no-cache<br/>
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01<br/>
Origin: http://localhost:8000<br/>
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest<br/>
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) <br/>AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 <br/>Safari/537.36<br/>
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8<br/>

Comment: **REQUEST PAYLOAD** (source view) {"candidate":{"fullname":"Jon Smith","email":"jon@gmail.com","password":"ew"}}